# how to hide item of the list in swiper js

Tags: swiper.js

I want to set show/hide items of the list in Swiper js.
Is there any simple solution?

```
 <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-item is-visible">Item 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-item is-visible">Item 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-item is-visible">Item 3</div>
 </div>
```